# Identity matrix of 3 Dimensional matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, 3d

```
Identity = array([[[1., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 1.]],

   [[1., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 1.]],

   [[1., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 1.]]])
```

There is a task which wants me to create identity matrix in 3D.

I have made assumptions that the above is the identity matrix in 3D with the shape (3,4,4).

I have seen other variations of identity of 3D matrix which I didn't understand. Check this [What's the best way to create a "3D identity matrix" in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029017/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-3d-identity-matrix-in-numpy) for reference.

If I am right in my above assumption  of identity matrix. Please assist me to construct the same with numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.identity()` to generate an identity matrix and then use `np.broadcast_to()` to add the third dimension:

```py
import numpy as np
n = 4
print(np.broadcast_to(np.identity(n), (3, n, n)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `np.tile`:

```
n = 4
k = 3
out = np.tile(np.identity(n), (k,1)).reshape(k,n,n)
```

Output:

```
[[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

 [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]]

 [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1.]]]
```