# Create numpy array of unit matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that takes a numpy array as argument to represent a physical 3D vector (with `shape=(3,)`) or an array of such vectors (with `shape=(3,n)`). In that function I need to form the 3x3 unit matrix or an array of 3x3 unit matrices, depending on the input. Thus

```
def func(x):
    if x.ndim == 1:
        unit = numpy.idenity(3)
    elif x.ndim == 2:
        unit = ???
        # should create 3D array of shape = (d,d,n) where x.shape=(d,n)
        # with entries unit[i,i,k]=1  and  unit[i,j,k]=0 for i≠j
```

(needless to say that I want an efficient way for this. Doing this by hand, i.e.

```
unit = np.zeros((3,3,n))
unit[0,0,:] = 1
unit[1,1,:] = 1
unit[2,2,:] = 1
```

is not what I want)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to create a "3D identity matrix" in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029017/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-3d-identity-matrix-in-numpy)

Answer (score 2):

A cute `np.einsum` method from my answer in the dupe target:

```
unit = np.zeros((3,3,n))
np.einsum('iij->ij', unit)[:] = 1
```

Pretty sure that's the fastest, shortest, and most bafflingly unreadable way to do it.

Comment: "bafflingly unreadable" doesn't even begin to describe it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an identity matrix and [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) it:

```
>>> np.eye(3).repeat(5, axis=-1)
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

The output shape is `(3, 3 * n)`, and then you need to `reshape` it once:

```
>>> np.eye(3).repeat(5, axis=-1).reshape(3, 3, -1)
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

---

The above solution is not more efficient than the three-step assignment in the question. If you want it to be faster, assigning values to slice with step is one method.

This time, we will merge the first two dims of the output first:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> unit = np.zeros((3*3, n))
```

Then assign the first dim of the output to 1 in steps of 4 (which is the size of the identitdy matrix plus 1):

```
>>> unit[::3+1] = 1
>>> unit
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

<sub>This kind of assignment is always effective for creating diagonal matrices, and in fact, this is exactly what [`np.eye`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) does.</sub>

Finally, perform a reshaping (which will not generate a copy):

```
>>> unit = unit.reshape(3, 3, -1)
>>> unit
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Comment: Okay, that works, but doesn't the repeat imply that a new array is created? In other words don't you first create a 3x3 array using `np.eye` and then a 3x3x5 array using `repeat`? This would be less efficient than directly creating the 3x3x5 array.

Comment: @Walter You are right. In fact, the solution you provided in the question is already fast enough. If you pursue faster speed, you may be intersted in an unreadable trick, which I will add to the answer later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to repeat the identity matrix n times:

```
import numpy as np

# assuming x.shape = (3, 2)
d, n = 3, 2
unit = np.identity(3)

# one way
r1 = np.repeat(unit, n).reshape(d, d, n)

# another way
r2 = np.repeat(unit.reshape(d,d,1), n, axis=-1)
```

Results in:

```
>>> print(r1)
array([[[1., 1.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]])

>>> print(r1[:, :, 0])
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

One package that is made for these kinds of operations is [einops](https://einops.rocks/) (i highly recommend it).

```
import einops as eo
import numpy as np

# assuming x.shape = (3, 2)
d, n = 3, 2
unit = np.identity(3)

r = eo.repeat(unit, 'd1 d2 -> d1 d2 n', n=2)
```

Comment: Still you create a temporary 3x3 unit matrix first. Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

As I want to avoid temporary arrays, I ended up creating a zero array and entering the ones on the diagonal(s):

```
def unit(x):
    """ create unit matrix/matrices """
    d = x.shape[0]
    if x.ndim == 1:
        return np.identity(d)
    else:
        n = x.shape[1]
        unit = np.zeros((d,d,n))
        elem = np.arange(0,d)
        unit[elem,elem,:] = 1.0
        return unit
```

Comment: Or, to avoid the indexing indirection: `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=a.shape[1:], strides=(sum(a.strides[:2]), a.strides[2]))[:]=1`. But it starts to be better only for huge values of `d`

Comment: Your `elem` indexer is a temporary array.  So only some realistic time tests would tell us if this is better than one of the `repeat` answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.broadcast_to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) though the result is not writeable:

```
def unit(x):
    if x.ndim == 1:
        return np.identity(x.shape[0])
    elif x.ndim > 1:
        d, n = x.shape[0], x.shape[1]
        return np.broadcast_to(np.identity(d)[..., None], (d, d, n))
    else:
        raise ValueError("x must be at least 1D")
```

Comment: A waste of 4 int64 : you use 9 when you could be using only 5 :D. `a=np.array([0,0,1,0,0]); np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a[2:], shape=(3,3,n), strides=(-a.strides[0],a.strides[0],0))`. (Just kidding of course. It works, sure, but broadcast does pretty much the same (the `0` strides part), with readable code)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`block_diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html) from `scipy` to create a diagonal array of 1's of the appropriate length (`x.shape[1]`) and then reshape that to your desired output:

```
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

def unit(x):
    if x.ndim == 1:
        return np.identity(x.shape[0])
    else:
        return block_diag(*np.ones(x.shape)).reshape(3,3,-1)

unit(np.zeros((3,)))
unit(np.zeros((3,2)))
unit(np.zeros((3,3)))
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])

array([[[1., 1.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.],
        [0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [1., 1.]]])

array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```